# BsonDocument ExtraElements Not Returning All Items

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, .net-core

I've built the following in C#, using MongoDB driver 2.7:

Class:

```
public class Address
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public long Building_Number { get; set; }
    public BsonDocument ExtraElements { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet("{number}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAddressByNumber(long number)
    {
        try
        {
            var address = _repository.GetAddressByNumber(number);

            if (address == null)
            {
                return new NotFoundResult();
            }

            return new ObjectResult(address);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

When I run an API to the controller, all the additional elements are placed into the ExtraElements, as expected.

The problem occurs when ObjectResult sends the result of the query back to the browser, only the first item is displayed (making the JSON invalid):

```
{
"id":
    {
        "timestamp":1540553241,
        "machine":3884863,
        "pid":-2023,
        "increment":3833504,
        "creationTime":"2018-10-26T11:27:21Z"
    },
    "building_Number":12345,
    "extraElements":
        [
            {
                "name":"Element01",
                "value":
                    {
                        "bsonType":2,
                        "rawValue":"I",
                        "value":"I"
```

I get a 404 returned by Postman, but I suspect this is due to the return being invalid.

I am at a loss to work out why these extra elements can be returned to the C# API correctly, but not returned to the caller from controller.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I omitted information that my project was using the .NET Core 2.0 framework.

It turns out that having updated the project to the latest .NET Core framework (2.1.5), has resolved the issue better than using the .ToJson() solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer to my question is/was as simple as the following:

```
return new ObjectResult(address.ToJson());
```